# How to highlight table row based on value in web2py?

Tags: python, html, view, web2py

I have a table that has some number of significant rows.

I want to highlight row based on value present in last column in web2py view

I tried doing

```
$('#stntable').dataTable({
    "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
        switch(aData[10]){
            case 'INSIGNIFICANT':
                $(nRow).css('color', 'orange')
                break;
            case 'NONE':
                $(nRow).css('color', 'green')
                break;
            case 'Station Experiencing Slugishness':
                $(nRow).css('color', 'red')
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

But it is not highlighting irrespective of what ?

Below how I have added id to table and building table

```
{{=TABLE(THEAD(TR([TH(c) for c in colnames])),
            (TR([TD(row) for row in rows])), _class = 'myTable', _id = "stntable")}}
```

How would I make changes

Thanks !

Comment: This is more of a DataTables question than a web2py/Python question. It would probably be better to show the generated HTML markup for the table, and tag this as a DataTables/jQuery/JavaScript question.

Comment: Are you sure the column in question is the 11th column (`aData[10]` will reference the value in the 11th column)?